# Symfony2 Doctrine correctly removing a ManyToMany relationship from object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have two objects `Product` and `Subcategory` with a `ManyToMany` relationship. The relationship is saved in a third table called `ProductSubcategory`.

The problem is that if I try to remove a subcategory from the product I get foreign constraint error (I can't remove from ProductSubcategory because it has values mapped to existing objects).

So what I did is added `onDelete=SET NULL` to my `ManyToMany` table. Now I can remove the subcategory, but what it does is it just sets the field `product` to NULL instead of deleting the whole thing.

In product I have:

```
/**
 * @var \Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductSubcategory
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductSubcategory", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $subcategory;
```

and a function to remove a subcategory:

```
/**
 * Remove subcategory
 *
 * @param \Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductSubcategory $subcategory
 */
public function removeSubcategory(\Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductSubcategory $subcategory) {
    foreach ($this->subcategory as $k => $s) {
        if ($s->getId() == $subcategory->getId()) {
            unset($this->subcategory[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

`ProductsSubcategory` is a `ManyToMany` table where I save the relationship:

```
/**
 * @var \Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Product
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="subcategory")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 * })
 */
private $product;
```

So if i do this:

```
$product->removeSubcategory($subcategory);
```

in database it just makes it null:

```
id|subcategory_id|product_id|
1 |2             |      NULL|
```

instead of completely removing it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `onDelete="CASCADE"` instead of `onDelete="SET NULL"` on the join column definition.

Comment: onDelte="CASCADE" removes both the product and the relationship

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still the right config, only maybe the wrong position. It's a bit hard to tinker with this as I don't have running code. I'd say, try the same config on `private $subcategory;` next. On a sidenote, you're talking about a `ManyToMany` relation, though I don't see it anywhere in your code, you only have two `ManyToOne/OneToMany` relations.